# Change URL in browser without redirection with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've looked everywhere to find the proper solution/method but I can't seem to find anything that **works for me.**
I even asked friends and they helped but none prevailed.

What i'm trying to do is, changing the URL displayed in the browser but only that. (No rediraction, page re-loading).
I want to do this to make my UCP just cleaner looking when going through certain pages/files.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
Heres an example on a profile, the URL would be:

```
mysite.com/ucp/profile.php?player=Heartfire
```

However, I want it to look like

```
mysite.com/ucp/profile/heartfire
```

Or something else! I just want to get rid of the parameters AFTER the .PHP

I've tried various examples found with google and this website but none seems to work, could somebody please guide me along the way to achieve the result.

**what have I tried so far?**
Here are a few examples of what I tried before:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$    /ucp/profile.php?player=$1
RewriteRule profile.php?player=$1 profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile$ profile.php?player=$1
```

So what am I doing wrong that it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in `.htaccess` file inside website's root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /ucp/profile\.php?([^=]+)=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ucp/profile\.php$ /ucp/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

# Now, deal with internal rewrites (which will not cause redirection):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ucp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /ucp/profile.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That did the trick (had to slightly edit it to make sure it didn't make you go back to the main page). However, it seems that it is not loading the CSS of the UCP.

Comment: @Heartfire Use `<base>` element in the `profile.php` file.

Comment: That did the trick! Appreciate all the assistance, I will put this newly acquired knowledge to good use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use internal redirects what will not change your url but map your request as your wanted.

What you want is impossible because:

Htaccess and rewrite is at server side. The request arrived to the server, need to rewrite at serverside and you need to change it in the clients url bar.

To achieve this the server should send a redirect with the url what you expected. This ia why redirect is mandatory. Server can't rewrite clients urls, just can send a redirect response.

Internal redirect can simulate you something like the request was what you expected but it is transparent at for the clients.

Btw, permanent redirect is the right solution here to notify the user and give the chance to let them know the resource has been changed and update the bookmark / api / whatever.