# htaccess - seo friendly url without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a website that has the following page:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services
```

Which can also have url parameters to vary what is shown

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services?grade=1093              // 1093 = medium)
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services?grade=2890              // 2890 = high)
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services?grade=2890&p=2          // p = page
```

I want to now be able to have these as seo-friendly/tidy urls but not have a 301 redirect. Ideally i'd like the urls above as an example to become:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services/medium-services
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services/high-services
http://www.mywebsite.com/our-services/high-services/page-2
```

Is this possible using htaccess? Am I right in thinking internal redirects with htaccess can achieve this without a redirect for the user? Looking on here I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912814/change-url-in-browser-without-redirection-with-htaccess#32913559) which is along the same lines but it is slightly different. Also when I try that example i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /ucp/profile\.php?([^=]+)=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ucp/profile\.php$ /ucp/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

# Now, deal with internal rewrites (which will not cause redirection):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ucp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /ucp/profile.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

When i've tested that in a dummy page when I go to:

```
mysite.com/ucp/profile.php?player=Heartfire
```

It gives me the following page:

```
mysite.com/ucp/?player/Heartfire%3f
```

It should be:

```
mysite.com/ucp/profile/heartfire
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `RewriteCond` needs tweaking to escape `?`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /ucp/profile\.php\?([^=]+)=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ucp/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# Now, deal with internal rewrites (which will not cause redirection):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ucp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ucp/profile.php?$1=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# new rules for /our-services/...
RewriteRule ^(our-services)/high-\w+/?$ $1?grade=2890 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(our-services)/high-\w+/page-(\d+)/?$ $1?grade=2890&p=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(our-services)/medium-\w+/?$ $1?grade=1093 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(our-services)/medium-\w+/page-(\d+)/?$ $1?grade=1093&p=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```